# How to completely isolate 2 operating systems on one disk

Tags: windows-10, dualboot

I'm going to have 2 instances of windows on my HDD and one of them will be prone to viruses. I want to make it so that it could not affect the other operating system and the files in its partitions. How can I do this?

I'm averse to using bare metal virtualization as I'm going to be gaming on the second operating system and its performance would be affected also its harder to setup.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make it so that it could not affect the other operating
> system and the files in its partitions. How can I do this? I'm averse to using bare metal virtualization

You will likely have issues, then.  Viruses have long learned to jump across internal connections (and local network connections).

This explains why keeping backups on the same system / network does not protect the backup from viruses like ransomware.

You should be able to make your Host system the Gaming System and virtualize the other system. That will not put a drag on the Host system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want true separation, partitions will not be enough.

Get a second hard drive.  Then you can enable and disable them in BIOS.  A virus cannot spread to a drive that isnt active.  The only issue then would be if you forget to disable one.  Encryption would prevent a virus from infecting another drive, but *not* from damaging it.  A virus might not be able to read another volume, but it can still erase it.

Alternatively, you can get a removable drive bay, like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=3.5%20inch%20interlnal%20%20trayless%20drive%20bay&sxsrf=ALiCzsYVfMeJhMK8jJ2GNcLyVew6V04_Dg%3A1661529580880&ei=7O0IY4KGNbuliLMPuNu3wAM&ved=0ahUKEwiCrM6D8OT5AhW7EmIAHbjtDTgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=3.5%20inch%20interlnal%20%20trayless%20drive%20bay&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgAEB4QogQyBQgAEKIEMgUIABCiBDIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEOgcIABBHELADOgQIIRAKSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUPggWNE3YOI8aARwAXgAgAHbBIgB4gySAQc5LjIuNS0xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz#oshopproduct=gid:17131114478484146920,mid:576462700072823972,oid:12045877283834453731,iid:14080972727189659479,rds:UENfMTcxMzExMTQ0Nzg0ODQxNDY5MjB8UFJPRF9QQ18xNzEzMTExNDQ3ODQ4NDE0NjkyMA%3D%3D,pvt:hg&oshop=apv) and swap as necessary.  There are removable drive bays for NVMe (PCIe cards), as well.  This give you the option to never have your primary drive and infected drive in the computer at the same time.

Comment: Was about to suggest the same. And I would just physically disconnect and reconnect both drives (USB or SATA), with just the BIOS it's easy enough to make a mistake and keep both hooked up. A physical motion reduces this chance.

Comment: @MiG same issues apply to physical.  You might *think* you disconnected one or the other, but didnt.  Allowing only one drive in the system completely eliminates 2 drives being active at once.  Plus physically opening a computer and swapping cables or drives is a pain.

Comment: That depends on how you do it really. For me, visual confirmation is enough, and muscle memory tends to help greatly here. Additionally you can colour code the drives, so you'll never them plug in simultaneously. And yeah, a dedicated system drive bay that only ONE of these two plugs into would help even more.

Answer (score 0):

[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) is able to encrypt partitions and have different passwords for each partition. Encrypt one instance with one password and use a different password for the other instance. The different instances will then not be able to see each other's files.

You will still be vulnerable to EFI or bootloader attacks. It would have to be specialized but the VeraCrypt bootloader is also vulnerable since it cannot be encrypted.